# New list environment not working in class file

Tags: memoir, fancyhdr, documentclass-writing

Sorry in advance for the length of this one....

The following MWE contains an enumerate environment I defined:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{argo}{enumerate}{1}
    \setlist[argo,1]{label=\arabic*.}
    \newcommand{\prem}{\item}
    \newcommand{\conc}{\rule{.3\linewidth}{1pt}\\[0em]\vspace{-3ex} \item[C.]}

\begin{document}

    \begin{argo}
        \prem Blah

        \prem Blah

        \conc Blah
    \end{argo}

\begin{multicols}{3}
        \begin{argo}
        \prem Blah

        \prem Blah

        \conc Blah
    \end{argo}

    \begin{argo}
        \prem Blah

        \prem Blah

        \conc Blah
    \end{argo}

    \begin{argo}
        \prem Blah

        \prem Blah

        \conc Blah
    \end{argo}

    \begin{argo}
        \prem Blah

        \prem Blah

        \conc Blah
    \end{argo}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

The main thing I'm looking to achieve is an environment for typesetting arguments in premise-conclusion form, where a rule is automatically inserted to separate the premises from the conclusion. I've included `multicols` because columns are what seems to mess things up.

Here is the PDF, with the list working as it should:

[image]

Once I embed this list definition into my .cls file, however, the behavior changes and the rules no longer properly scale to 1/3 line width. Like so:

[image]

Here is the custom `.cls` file I'm working with:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{dkhandout}[2014/05/04 DK Handout]
\LoadClass[article,oneside,oldfontcommands]{memoir}

%%%%%LOAD FOLLOWING PACKAGES%%%%%
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{geometry}
\let\footruleskip\undefined % makes memoir compatible with fncyhdr
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{datetime}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
\RequirePackage{multicol}
%%%%%CLASS OPTIONS%%%%%%%%%%%%

\DeclareOption{10pt}{
  \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{memoir}
}
\DeclareOption{11pt}{
  \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{memoir}
}
\DeclareOption{12pt}{
  \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{memoir}
}
%% Fallback
\DeclareOption*{
  \ClassWarning{myclass}{Unknown option '\CurrentOption'}
}
%%%%%DEFAULT CLASS OPTIONS%%%%%%%
\ExecuteOptions{10pt}

%%%%%PROCESS OPTIONS%%%%%%%%%%
\ProcessOptions\relax

%%%%%HEADER OPTIONS%%%%%%%%%%%

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\thetitle}
\rhead{Phil 164 - \ifnumcomp{\value{MONTH}}{<}{7}{Spring}{Fall} \the\year}%

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \lhead{\thetitle}%
  \rhead{Phil 164 - \ifnumcomp{\value{MONTH}}{<}{7}{Spring}{Fall} \the\year}%
}

%%%%%DOCUMENT FORMATTING%%%%%%%
    % Title flush left and compact spacing
    \pretitle{\vspace*{-10ex}\flushleft\Large\bfseries}
    \posttitle{\par\vspace{0em}}
    \preauthor{\par\vspace{0em}}
    \postauthor{\par\vspace{0em}}
    \predate{\par\vspace{0em}}
    \postdate{\par\vspace{5ex}}

    % No paragraph indentation
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \nonzeroparskip

   % Blank date and author
    \date{}
    \author{}

    % New argument environment "argo"
    \newlist{argo}{enumerate}{1}
    \setlist[argo,1]{label=\arabic*.}
    \newcommand{\prem}{\item}
    \newcommand{\conc}{\rule{.3\linewidth}{1pt}\\ \relax \vspace{-3ex} \item[C.]}

%%%%%END OF CLASS%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\endinput
```

Some tinkering gives me the vague impression that `fancyhdr` is to blame, but this is my first `.cls` and so I might have done something wrong at an even more basic level.

So what is going wrong here? Why does the rule (and only the rule) get messed up when I put the list definition in a .cls file?

Comment: If you suspect `fancyhdr`, comment it out and test. I have an environment which I use for this defined in a class file but I seem to have hard-coded the length of the line. (I doubt this was because I had problems - I think this is probably just how I did it.)

Comment: Use `\newcommand{\conc}{\rule{.3\columnwidth}{1pt}\par \vspace{-1ex} \item[C.]}` Note `\columnwidth`  : http://i.stack.imgur.com/kNWIC.png

Comment: A short advice: your class file (or rather the user) will get into trouble as soon as another inputencoding or another engine than `pdflatex` is used. Be aware of that and take the needed precautions.

Comment: @HarishKumar Sorry, I'd totally forgotten about this question. Your comment fixed my problem, so if you'd like to turn it into an answer I'd be happy to accept it to get this guy off of the unanswered list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Converting comment in to answer</sub>

Use `\columnwidth` instead of `\linewidth` in

```
\newcommand{\conc}{\rule{.3\columnwidth}{1pt}\par \vspace{-1ex} \item[C.]} Note \columnwidth
```

This gives:

[image]